# Infinite selenium refresh with python

Tags: python, selenium

I use selenium to automate my process within a website. What happens is that I want it to keep loading the page until it finds an element.

The element will appear when I do something from another tab on the page.

I get the following error:
**selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span"}**

But, it doesn't appear right away. I tried the following code and it didn't work:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    time.sleep(3)
    search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span")
    print('found')
    time.sleep(3)
    search.send_keys('test')
except NoSuchElementException: 
    print('not found')
    pass
```

The page reloads, but it only does it once, not infinitely.

## Solution

```
while True:
            delay()
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span")
                print('Found product in cart')
                delay()
                boton_finalizar_compra = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/button')
                boton_finalizar_compra.click()
                
            except NoSuchElementException: 
                print('Not found product in cart')
                driver.refresh()
```